# Excel 2007 “Arbitrary” #NAME? Errors

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In the midst of writing the first question I had, I accidentally found the solution (sort of). The issue I was having was when pasting texts that started with hyphens, Excel would (seemingly) randomly distribute #NAME? errors. Obviously I know that error is because the hyphen is an operator and Excel is looking to act on some range or value with it. What I didn't know is that the errors weren't random -- they appear in any cell that does not include a parenthesis.

EXAMPLES (must be pasted without the quotes, obviously) --

(returns error when pasted into a cell)

"- Stamped"

(does not return error when pasted)

"- Stamped ("

So now, armed with this knowledge, I have a new question: Since I am just copying text into excel that we receive from outside sources, and sometimes those strings will have a parenthesis and sometimes they won't (but they'll always start with a hyphen), is there any way for me to alter this behavior from Excel? For instance, can I act on the text that shows up in the function bar, even when the cell returns a #NAME? error? I've tried to =IFERROR and =CONCATENATE to add an apostrophe to the beginning of the function to resolve the error, but I can't use a function on the problem cell while it still evaluates to an error.

Because I'm copying this data (in large quantities) from an external text source, is there anything I can do besides just pasting it first into notepad and manually adding parentheses where needed? That seems rather wasteful.

Comment: Format the cell as text before pasting the values.

Comment: I found the same thing if Office 2013, I convert the column to text first then paste your data it works.  If I don't change the format first, Office 2013 will now allow the posting to happen

Comment: It seems formatting as text first has eliminated the problem, which is great. However, I'm now still interested why cells that contain any parentheses, in any context, doesn't return the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if you can format the column as Text first, then paste, that solves many practical issues.

Not all of them though.

Another approach would be to paste the data, then, while still selected, do a `Find and Replace`. Of what? You will notice that all the cases in which the error occurs, there is an "=" in the cell:  `=- Stamp`  as an example. The "=" can be replaced with a single quote character:  `'` and now the data is treated as text.

(The error comes from Excel thinking, because of the hyphen, that you were trying to get the result of "subtract the Named Range 'Stamp' ". Since there is no such Name, it returns the #NAME? error.)

Strictly speaking, Excel wants to find such text with double quotes around it so it knows it is text. It is OK with finding the  `(` since a Name cannot have a space in it so it knows it is not a Named Range and tries treating it as text instead. Which works for you.

Unfortunately, getting the second `"` added takes a formula as Excel only offers Regex via VBA and if you wanted to use VBA, none of this would have come up at all so... Best to just not worry about the fringes unless formatting the column first does not solve things for you. Or using `Find and Replace` to remove the "=" is not desired (you might want to just paste and "it works"... not to do a couple steps after that).

Under no circumstance MUST you work on the data in NotePad as Excel offers ways to do all you need. But you could prefer it. And I believe NotePad++ does Regex which could be nice. The formatting idea, the `Find and Replace` idea, or using formulas to clean it up, or any combination, will serve decently. This is not one of Excel's obnoxious and unsolvable problems, just one of its obnoxious ones.